# AsNoTracking() don't work if to the method with IEnumerable result to add AsQueryable()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework and have the next code:

```
var rating = repository
   .GetByFilter(r => r.EntityId == dto.EntityId)
   .Result
   .AsQueryable();

return rating.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
```

And every time when I want to update an entity I got the next error:
*The instance of entity type 'Rating' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked*...

GetByFilter method returns Task<IEnumerable < T >>

Could you please tell why AsNoTracking doesn't work with AsQueryable?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you calling `Result`? Do you know what that does?

Comment: there is Task<IEnumerable < T >>, the <T> part disappeared when I published the question

Answer (score 1):

The entity you are trying to get untracked at `.FirstOrDefault()` is already tracked. Therefore, it cannot be loaded again with as no tracking.

Comment: After AsNoTracking the entity becomes untracked and only after AsTracking it can be tracked again. So `.FirstOrDefault()` isn't the reason.

Answer (score 1):

So many issues in 5 lines of code...

1. Looks like `GetByFilter` already instantiated objects and registered them in ChangeTracker. For example by `ToList` or `ToListAsync`.
2. Also, again, looks like `GetByFilter` is asynchronous method and calling `.Result` of the task is the worst idea ever. Use `await` always! or do not create asynchronous methods.
3. Calling `AsNoTracking` for `IEnumerable` will never work. It should be `IQueryable` created from `DbSet` but not `IQueryable` from `IEnumerable`.
4. It is too late to call `FirstOrDefault` - whole table populated into the memory or server forced to return whole table (depending on filter).

What to do (variants)

Create additional method `GetByFilterNoTrackedAsync` (name async methods with suffix `Async`) in your repository, which calls `AsNoTracked` before materialisation.

Remove generic repository pattern completely because instead of helping it forces to create boilerplate. `DbContext` is already Unit of Work, `DbSet` is already repository.

And just call clear and effective query:

```cs
var rating = await ctx.DbSet<SomeEntity>()
   .Where(r => r.EntityId == dto.EntityId)
   .AsNoTracking()
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

return rating;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for so detailed response and advices! Let me clarify a little bit) This is not my project so I can't remove the generic repository but I'm aware of it. And also I don't want to write a new method there so I decide to use the written one. With Result it is my fault, I'm not so good at these but I'm studying it) Wishing you all the best!

Comment: With this one method you will get only performance problems.

Comment: @VitaliiIvanchuk Strongly advise reading the points in this answer, especially 1 and 3. The original problem is caused by the design/implementation of the repository method. What you are trying to do is similar to `new List<Something>().AsEnumerable().AsQueryable().AsNoTracking()`.  The `IQueryable` implementation here is from LINQ to Objects, and `AsNoTracking` (as well as other EFC specific extensions like `Include`, `AsSplitQuery()` etc.) work only with EFC queryable implementation, or more precisely the queryable *query provider*, which is responsible for handling them.

Comment: The query provider from L2O has no idea what these methods are, and will just compile and execute them. But at the time of execution it is too late - the EFC query (translated to SQL) has been already executed.